# Can I get bubble tea at Taipei Taoyuan airport?

Tags: food-and-drink, tpe

I already liked bubble tea before but I now know that Taiwanese bubble tea is next level. Sadly, I was only here for a long weekend and fly back tomorrow morning.

Is there a place at Taipei Taoyuan airport where I can get one last Taiwanese bubble tea before I leave?

It doesn’t matter whether it’s land or airside, I can set aside time on either.

Answer (score 15):

[Chun Shui Tang (Taoyuan Airport branch)](https://www.google.com/search?q=chun+shui+tang+(taoyuan+airport)) (春水堂) has some Taiwanese bubble tea.

Information:

- https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g13806459-d5453072-Reviews-Chun_Shui_Tang_Taoyuan_Airport-Dayuan_Taoyuan.html
- Location: Gate/Area: Terminal 2, Floor B2 (https://www.ifly.com/taipei-chiang-kai-shek-international-airport/TPE-Terminal-2) ([mirror](http://archive.is/8gCrP))
- Phone: +886-3-393-1385

[image]

(image source: https://kosublog.com/en/taipei-1704-part13/)

[Coco都可](http://www.coco-tea.com.cn/) (bubble tea chain) also has a branch at Taipei Taiyuan airport in Terminal 2, Floor B2: https://www.yelp.com/biz/coco%E9%83%BD%E5%8F%AF-%E6%A1%83%E5%9C%92%E7%B8%A3%E5%A4%A7%E5%9C%92%E9%84%89-2?hrid=w1XAJghPFv0N31lnFDhQMw

[image]

(image source: https://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/coco%E9%83%BD%E5%8F%AF-%E6%A1%83%E5%9C%92%E7%B8%A3%E5%A4%A7%E5%9C%92%E9%84%89-2?select=aEek5y7dgU6XJvkldFAiVw)

Comment: Not so fun fact: I wasn’t able to locate either stall and to make matters worse the layout of the food court seemed nothing like the one I saw on Apple Maps. I wonder if there has been a recent redesign with contractors changing …

Comment: @Jan sorry to hear, did you get a chance to ask the information desk or other restaurants?

Comment: There was one other stall, that I took a picture of (and will possibly add as an answer in due course) but it was a disappointment compared to what I had the days before.

Answer (score 1):

The milk tea or boba or bubble tea places that are worth visiting at Taoyuan airport are outside of security. There is a place inside security and it was horrendous (boba was hard and chalky).

Coco a famous local drink franchise (milk tea and fruit tea) is in terminal 1. There is a 'come buy tea' in B1 (basement level) food court - outside of security.